# Unable to build rust's Rocket project because of framework dependency error

Tags: rust

I'm following [this tutorial here](https://medium.com/sean3z/building-a-restful-crud-api-with-rust-1867308352d8) and have also looked into [Rocket's official guide](https://rocket.rs/v0.4/guide/getting-started/#installing-rust) of setting up a web server.

I've set as default the *nightly* builds. But I get the following error:

```
error: failed to select a version for the requirement `ring = "^0.11.0"`
  candidate versions found which didn't match: 0.16.11, 0.16.10, 0.16.9, ...
  location searched: crates.io index
required by package `cookie v0.9.1`
    ... which is depended on by `rocket v0.3.6`
    ... which is depended on by `my-project`
```

Obviously there's some mismatch with the dependencies, but since `ring` is something required by the framework itself, I'm not sure how to debug this... furthermore, I'm using the latest versions of cargo and rust:

```
cargo 1.43.0-nightly (... 2020-02-18)
rustc 1.43.0-nightly (... 2020-02-21)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ring v0.11.0` [was yanked](https://crates.io/crates/ring/versions) from `crates.io` (see [this issue](https://github.com/briansmith/ring/issues/774) for some background). Since some versions `rocket` depended on versions of `ring` that were yanked, those versions of `rocket` will no longer work.

Upgrading to `rocket v0.4.0` (or the latest `v0.4.2`) should solve this issue.